# Why does clicking icon reload angular page

Tags: angular, angular5, ng-bootstrap

I've got an angular 5 app that is exhibiting some strange (to me) behavior.  I've got an icon in an accordion:

```
    <ngb-accordion>
        <ngb-panel *ngFor="let subspace of lab.subSpaces" #group>
            <ng-template ngbPanelTitle>
                {{ subspace.name }}
                <button *ngIf="isLabManager" class="float-right"
                        style="margin-bottom: 0;margin-right: 10px;"
                        (click)="deleteSubSpace(subspace)">
                    <i class="fa fa-trash btn btn-danger"></i>
                </button>
            </ng-template>
```

When I click on that icon the `deleteSubSpace` code runs but at the same time the page then reloads to the home page of the angular app, and I can't for the life of me figure out why.  The code is just removing a subspace from the list:

```js
deleteSubSpace(subspace: SubSpace): void {
    const index = this.lab.subSpaces.findIndex(x => x.id == subspace.id);
    if (index !== -1) {
        this.lab.subSpaces.splice(index, 1);
    }
}
```

I realize removing an element from the list will cause that sub-component to have to refresh, but if I'm currently at a URL of /details/1234, when I remove the item, why is the page reloading at / instead of /details/1234?

More strangeness.  If I put this code in the `ngOnInit`:

```js
setTimeout(() => this.deleteSubSpace(this.lab.subSpaces[1]), 5000);
```

then 5 seconds after loading the subspace cleanly goes away.  So clearly nothing wrong with the delete method.  Somehow calling that method from a `(click)` handler is causing the reload.

Comment: Have you checked the generated HTML to see if any links are generated as ancestors of the element? You could also set a breakpoint on page-unload to check the stack to see what's triggering the navigation (in Chrome DevTools, this is under Source -> Event Listener Breakpoints -> Load -> `beforeunload`).

Comment: Looks like it's breaking on `globalZoneAwareCallback` in `zone.js`

Comment: are any http requests being made when you click the icon? doesn't look like it but thought i'd ask in case an http interceptor is doing the redirect

Comment: are you shure that (click) on fontawesome icon works properly? depending on how you use fontawsome the <i> DOM element can be changed with <svg> one.

Comment: I tried putting an actual button as well for the click.  what it seems like is happening as that because the code modifies the array, which the `*ngFor` is using, that when the item comes out it reloads that part, and that for some reason is jumping back to a full reload instead of just updating the list of items on that page.

Comment: Added a bit more context to the question around a timeload delete not having the issue.

Comment: If I move the button OUT of the ngbPanelTitle and into the ngbPanelContent then there is no issue.  So definitely an ng-bootstrap bug at this point I think!

Comment: Did you try to put `type="button"` on the `<button>`?